# Checkout multiple branches in one pipeline

Tags: azure-devops, yaml, azure-pipelines, git-checkout

I'm trying to get two different branches in one pipeline so that I can compare directories. When I do it like this it works.

```
- checkout: self
- checkout: 'git://MyRepo/MyProject'
  path: master
```

The problem becomes when I need to checkout the branch for pull request, not the merge branch that is created for the pull request automatically by the server. So I do it like this:

```
- checkout: 'git://MyRepo/MyProject@$(System.PullRequest.SourceBranch)'
  path: s
- checkout: 'git://MyRepo/MyProject@master'
  path: master
```

The issue here is that the second checkout moves the data from the source (`$(Build.SourcesDirectory)`) directory to the `master` directory.

> Repository is current at 'E:\vsts-buildser98-agent03_work\230\s\MyProject', move to
> 'E:\vsts-buildser98-agent03_work\230\master'.
> Repository will be located at 'E:\vsts-buildser98-agent03_work\230\master'.

This cause fail in build and actually everything I need to do before the compare. Moreover the `Post-job: Checkout` fails since the first directory doesn't exist anymore.

Answer (score 0):

You have specified a `path` in the `checkout` step, so the behavior is correct.

When a `path` is specified for a `checkout` step, that path is used, relative to `(Agent.BuildDirectory)`.

You could check more information of checkout path in the following link:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/repos/multi-repo-checkout?view=azure-devops#checkout-path

Comment: Even with the path specified it cleared the first directory.

Comment: Do you mean the second checkout replace the path of first checkout? Could you share the logs for two checkout? In my test, only second checkout move to “master" folder.